# How do modify image data in SlidesShowPro using Flash ActionScript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, slideshow

I'm using SlideShowPro with Flash AS3 and I have the following code:

```
function onSlideShowClick(event:SSPImageEvent) {
  if (event.type == "imageClick") {
    // modify the link for when the image is clicked.
  }
}
```

How can I modify the link for when the image is clicked?  Can that be done here?  Elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out with some help from the API docs.

```
public function onSlideShowData(event:SSPDataEvent):void {
  if (event.type == "imageData") {
    // Modify the image link.
    event.data.link = "http://somedomain.com/?url=" + escape(event.data.link);
  }
}
my_ssp.addEventListener(SSPDataEvent.IMAGE_DATA, onSlideShowData);
```

Reference API docs: http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPfl/API-AS3Event-imageData

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving something like this a whirl...

```
var currentLink:String = "";

function onSlideShowData(event:SSPDataEvent) {
  currentLink = event.link;
}
my_ssp.addEventListener(SSPDataEvent.IMAGE_DATA, onSlideShowData);

function onSlideShowClick(event:SSPImageEvent) {
  if (event.type == "imageClick") {

    // Alter the image link
    currentLink = currentLink + "?someparam=somevalue";

    // Send the user to the altered url.
    flash.net.navigateToURL(currentLink);
  }
}
my_ssp.addEventListener(SSPImageEvent.IMAGE_CLICK, onSlideShowClick);
```

It basically stores the current `link` (assuming you [defined one in the xml](http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPfl/UG-CreatingLinks)) to a variable whenever the image changes. Then when you click an image it just uses the standard `navigateToUrl()` method.

Now, I have some doubts that this will work because you aren't able to cancel the `SSPImageEvent` from within the handler function, and therefore I think that SSP will just fire the `navigateToURL()` function on whatever was defined in the xml immediately after your handler executes. But give it a try.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to programmatically alter the target URLs.

Comment: I just updated my answer. It should theoretically allow you to do that, though I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks jessegavin, your example told me that I should look at onSlideShowData instead of onSlideShowClick.